# Better to change parent's field or override getter?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Let's say I have a `Projectile` class which acts as a base class for all projectiles in my game. This contains default values for maximum speed, gravity coefficient, bounce coefficient, etc.

```
public abstract class Projectile {

    protected float maxSpeed = 100.0f;
    protected float gravityCoefficient = 1.0f;
    protected float bounceCoefficient = 1.0f;
    ...

}
```

I then have a bunch of subclasses, each of which may choose to override some of these default values.

Which is the better approach here?

**1. Set field values in child constructor**

```
public class Arrow {

    public Arrow(){
        super();
        maxSpeed = 200.0f;
    }

}
```

**2. Make child override getter**

```
public class Arrow {

    public float getMaxSpeed(){
        return 200.0f;
    }

}
```

I am inclined to say that the first approach is better, since it means the field can be accessed directly without the need for any extra function calls. However, it does mean that the value is set twice during object creation, once by the parent and once by the child.

Am I missing anything here? Is there, perhaps, another approach?

Comment: Approach 1 would be the right way to go

Comment: The first approach ist he better one. There is no downside that you are able to observe, but the secon approach is a really bad practice. Instead having a getter that return a fixed value you could also use a static class constant.

Comment: Personally I'd make the field private - and final if possible - and introduce a `Projectile` constructor which allows subclasses to specify the value.

Comment: Why don't you use a constructor with a _speed_ parameter?

Comment: Constructor, please.  If your concern is performance, it doesn't matter.  Responsibility is the better argument.

Comment: @JonSkeet Have a doubt here, the first approach breaks the principle of Encapsulation ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ How does that violate encapsulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, the maximum speed of any particular projectile is unlikely to vary over its lifetime (even in the case where different instances of the same type *can* have different maximum speeds), therefore I would favour a final field for it. I would also favour making it final - I very rarely use non-private fields, other than for genuine constants.

As you have some state (the field) for `Projectile`, I would avoid allowing the confusion of having the maximum speed has revealed by `getMaxSpeed` differing from the field.

I would probably design it like this:

```
public abstract class Projectile {
    private final float maxSpeed;

    protected Projectile(float maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    // Only if you really need this...
    protected Projectile() {
        this(200f);
    }

    public final getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
}

public class Arrow extends Projectile {
    public Arrow() {
        super(100f);
    }
}
```

The gravity coefficient and bounce coefficient may be treated in a similar way - or if all of these really act as "the same values for every instance of a particular type" you could introduce a new class to represent these constants, which separates the varying state of instances of a type from the constant restrictions/coefficients - and each instance could just have a final reference to an instance of that new class. Unfortunately Java (and at least some similar languages) don't really model this kind of hierarchy well. It's always an annoyance :(

Comment: I'm not too happy about the idea of supplying all of these values as parameters to the parent constructor, because there might be a lot of them, and most of the time the children should just inherit the default values from the parent. However, I DO like the idea of introducing a new class to keep the per-instance and per-type variables separate. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan: And the good news is that once you've got that extra class, you only need one parameter in the constructor.

Comment: if it is indeed per-type constant, perhaps maxspeed should be static?

Comment: @sharponb: No, because then you can't find the maximum speed of any projectile. Using *just* a property with no field would allow that, but it's annoying in other ways. This issue is what my final paragraph is about. It comes up quite often, and is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

you should have a setter and use it, that is what setters are for. It will allow you to keep the field private. The other benefit is that using Java Bean convention will allow you to use libraries such as [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) to populate and manipulate your Objects. You will also be able to persist your data in DB or file.

```
public abstract class Projectile {

    private float maxSpeed = 100.0f;  // default 

    protected void setMaxSpeed(float newSpeed) {
        maxSpeed = newSpeed;
    }
}

public class Arrow extends Projectile {

    public Arrow() {
        super();
        setMaxSpeed(200.0f);  // arrow specific values
    }
}
```

Comment: I would only add a setter if the maximum speed of an object can actually vary over its lifetime - which at least *sounds* unlikely to me. It feels more likely that the speed can vary, but not the maximum speed - in which case it would make more sense for it to be a final field, set in the constructor.

Comment: that is a good case. but suppose you want to load the values from an xml file (i.e. allow for modding the game?) it is much easier if you follow java beans convention and be able to use 3rd party library. otherwise you will have to have custom loader

Comment: That sounds like an exception rather than the rule to me. I prefer to make state final unless I have a good reason not to - in this case, it looks like the maximum speed depends on the type more than on any instance of the type (at least for Arrow) so why would I want to save that value in the XML file anyway?

Comment: 1) values may change with game difficulty or possible other run time modifiers 2) you may wish to 
tweak the values during beta testing

Comment: So provide the values in a constructor. Neither of them need to be changed during the lifetime of an instance. Fixing as much as you can (ideally everything, with immutable types) can make code a *lot* easier to understand. Obviously that's not the case for all types and all state, but looking at this *particular* example, I don't think a setter is a good idea.

Comment: IMO you didn't give a satisfying answer to the points I raised. you favor sticking to the rules of OO design over all else. I say that having the possibility to test the game with diiferent values by replacing xml files (or giving this possibiity to modders) is a trump card that provides the reason to deviate from strict OO design

Comment: You can easily load XML files in a way that passes the values to the constructor if you really want to. I don't see that as a "trump card" to violate good design at all. Or you could load an XML file into a mutable type as a configuration, then create an immutable factory from that, to make it clear that the values won't change over the lifetime of the object. Unnecessary mutability is a very real pain in terms of maintainability, IMO.

Comment: like I said, this will require a custom loader that can call the specific ctor. and what if OP wishes to save values in DB ? you would write a custom ORM as well??

Comment: I would probably save the state of each individual arrow in a different table to the configuration for arrows in general - indicating that all arrows will have the same maximum speed. Note that all of these use cases are only being imagined *by you* - they certainly don't reflect any requirements specified by the OP. I would prefer to stick to sound OO designs until there's a concrete reason to violate them - at which point the trade-offs can be evaluated - rather than saying "Well you *might* want to do X, so let's just throw all design principles out of the window, just in case."

Comment: since you raised the point: the assumption that "all arrows will have the same maximum speed" is also your imagination. immutability is not mentioned in the question as given requirement. I view the question as general regarding setting instance variables of super in ctor of concrrete subclass

Comment: It's not my imagination - it comes from the fact that the override in the question returns a constant value. Calling `getMaxSpeed` on any `Arrow` instance (not a subclass, but an `Arrow`) will return the same value... Anyway, I don't think we're going to agree on this. I will continue to follow OO designs unless there's a concrete compelling reason to do so - I can't imagine you persuading me out of that stance.

Comment: IMO, the getter is written as is for brevity. the question is setting value in ctor vs. overriding getter

Comment: I guess we agree to disagree :)

Comment: In my case, maxSpeed is a per-type constant, so I am starting to agree with Jon Skeet that a setter is perhaps not the best option as it makes this value mutable. Were that not the case, this would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

First approach. Declare a method named modifyDefaults() in your abstract base class. Implement it in each class and call in the constructor so that whenever someone sees abstract class, it can be concluded that you will be modifying defaults in children.

Or just hand over responsibility of Projectile creation to a projectileFactory if there are only a few deciding parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your inclination towards the first answer should be. It does clearly state the following:

- The child class has it's responsibility of creating it's own instance variables (properties)
- Overriding of getter, though sounds good at certain views, doesn't usually give a good maintainability. Constructor clearly states the extra set of property defaults whatsoever very cleanly.

I'm not sure about your design, but if you have your super class which doesn't have state of it's own, try making it `abstract` and the design changes completely than we discussed in that case (option 2 might be considered that time).

Answer (score -1):

For java, compiler optimization and JIT optimization are of great importance for the improvement of performance.
The second piece of code will be much more easier to be optimized with no worry of extra operations.

Comment: I would favour design over performance until performance has been proven critical. If any code in the base class uses the field instead of the method, it will lead to errors. Having state on one field and then "overriding" it with a method returning a different constant value feels like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: Yes, in most cases it's not a good design, but, from my point of view, if in subclass the maxSpeed is a constant, this way can be OK!

Comment: So why not set the field, and have one consistent view, rather than contradictory state?

Comment: if the subclass do not to want maxSpeed? It's encapsulation and hide in OOP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment at all... But as the superclass already has a field for this piece of state, I think having a separate value for it elsewhere is a really bad idea.

Comment: I approve your answer, too. But I think I my answer is also useful for questioner. We are just from different point of view.

Comment: I haven't posted an answer... But this one just feels like bad advice to me, I'm afraid - it feels like the kind of approach that only leads to confusion, with no benefits.

Comment: Yes, I think it's basically a bad approach. There would have to be a really good reason to do it - one which I can't immediately imagine.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88368/discussion-between-tian-and-jon-skeet).